# How does Modelica check the structural singularity?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

In Example 1 from chapter 4.7 of [Modelica specification 3.4](https://specification.modelica.org/master/class-predefined-types-and-declarations.html#balanced-models), I am not sure why there is no structural singularity. I add two equations generated according to the flow variables, and it seems this equation system doesn't have a unique solution.

So why isn't there structural singularity in this example?

[image]

I add the two equations(`p.i=0  n.i=0`) according to the paper [Balanced Models in Modelica 3.0 for Increased Model Quality](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Balanced-Models-in-Modelica-3.0-for-Increased-Model-Olsson-Otter/cc7f07def50006c2f2dc3629d27551ecee9bcddf?p2df), here is the screenshot of this paper.

How should I understand the concept of "generic coupling" for top-level connectors? Does it mean setting the flow variables as zero or constant?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I recall the generic coupling means that:

```
 p.i=f1(p.v, n.v);
 n.i=f2(p.v, n.v);
```

for some unspecified (or generic) functions `f1` and `f2`; not the trivial function `p.i=0`. (Possibly it is some variant of this.)

Note that quoted text is for the reverse case; where you have a `replaceable Load C`.